# What are the examples of NP problems that is reducible to a NP-complete but not the other way round?

Tags: p-np

What are the examples of NP problems that is reducible to NP-complete problem but not the other way round? When I read about NP and NP-complete, I thought the mapping will be one-one such that it is stupid to categorize them. However, surely there are problems where it can only be reducible in one direction. I am interested to know them.

Answer (score 0):

All NP problems can be reduced to NP-complete problems. NP-complete problems are a special type of NP problems. Therefore, NP-complete problems don't need to be reduced to be considered to be in NP; they're already in NP.